# How to add median and standard deviation for each condition

Tags: r

My data look like this

```
df<-structure(list(Data = c("P718", "Trans17", "Ham8Y"), Rep1_Condition = c(30100000, 
1.11e+10, 2.05e+09), Rep2_Condition = c(37700000, 1.3e+10, 3.52e+09
), Rep3_Condition = c(4.27e+10, 0, 1.75e+10), Rep1_H1 = c(4.49e+08, 
1.28e+11, 5.5e+10), Rep2_H1 = c(4.31e+08, 1.5e+11, 6.38e+10), 
    Rep3_H1 = c(3.89e+10, 0, 1.89e+10), Rep1_H2 = c(4.07e+08, 
    1.24e+11, 4.41e+10), Rep2_H2 = c(1.98e+08, 8.21e+10, 3.14e+10
    ), Rep3_H2 = c(1.75e+10, 0, 1.46e+09)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I want to add median and SD for each 3 replicate for example

```
P718  3.01e+07  3.77e+07  4.27e+10
```

The value can be next to it

Something like this structure

```
out<- structure(list(Data = c("P718", "Trans17", "Ham8Y"), Rep1_Condition = c(30100000, 
1.11e+10, 2.05e+09), Rep2_Condition = c(37700000, 1.3e+10, 3.52e+09
), Rep3_Condition = c(4.27e+10, 0, 1.75e+10), Condition_median = c(NA, 
NA, NA), Condition_SD = c(NA, NA, NA), Rep1_H1 = c(4.49e+08, 
1.28e+11, 5.5e+10), Rep2_H1 = c(4.31e+08, 1.5e+11, 6.38e+10), 
    Rep3_H1 = c(3.89e+10, 0, 1.89e+10), H1_Median = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), H1_SD = c(NA, NA, NA), Rep1_H2 = c(4.07e+08, 1.24e+11, 
    4.41e+10), Rep2_H2 = c(1.98e+08, 8.21e+10, 3.14e+10), Rep3_H2 = c(1.75e+10, 
    0, 1.46e+09), H2_Median = c(NA, NA, NA), H2_SD = c(NA, NA, 
    NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Do you need new columns i.e. `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Data, names_to = c("grp", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% group_by(Data) %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), list(median= ~ median(.x), SD = ~ sd(.x))))`

Comment: @akrun
this is wrong. we have 3 samples, each samples have 3 replicate in condition , 3 replicate in H1 and 3 replicate in H2. I want the median and SD in another column next to each condition . I will try to put an example above

Comment: @akrun I just posted an example of output

Comment: My solution was to get the sd, median in long format which may be useful for you to plot.  If you want the wide `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Data, names_to = c("grp", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% group_by(Data) %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), list(median= ~ median(.x), SD = ~ sd(.x)))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Condition:H2_SD)`

Comment: @akrun
 Column `H2_SD` doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, in the pivot_wider, i selected all columns `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Data, names_to = c("grp", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>% group_by(Data) %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), list(median= ~ median(.x), SD = ~ sd(.x)))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Condition:H2)`

Comment: @akrun
 should I get only one value for median per each sample for 3 condition? in your solution I get 3?

Comment: It is returning median or sd per row for each set of columns

Comment: @akrun
sorry I guess you got things wrong. If you look at the data, it is not per column, for instance `P718  3.01e+07  3.77e+07  4.27e+10` these are 3 values for one sample across 3 conditions. they must get 1 median

Comment: That is what it did, please check the values in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` excluding the 'Data' column, then grouped by 'Data', `mutate` across the `numeric` columns to create two additional columns `median`, `SD` (as there are multiple columns, this returns as suffix names when we apply the functions in a `named` list), finally, reshape back to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` (

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out2 <- df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -Data, names_to = c("grp", ".value"), 
     names_sep = "_") %>% 
   group_by(Data) %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), 
     list(median= ~ median(.x), SD = ~ sd(.x)))) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Condition:H2)
```

-checking

```
> out2$Condition_median
[1] 3.77e+07 1.11e+10 3.52e+09
> matrixStats::rowMedians(as.matrix(df[2:4]))
[1] 3.77e+07 1.11e+10 3.52e+09
```

-output

```
> out2
# A tibble: 3 × 16
  Data    Condition_median Condition_SD    H1_median     H1_SD H2_median   H2_SD Condition_Rep1 Condition_Rep2 Condition_Rep3 H1_Rep1 H1_Rep2 H1_Rep3
  <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 P718            37700000 24633284613.    449000000   2.22e10   4.07e 8 9.93e 9       30100000       37700000    42700000000 4.49e 8 4.31e 8 3.89e10
2 Trans17      11100000000  7021633238. 128000000000   8.10e10   8.21e10 6.31e10    11100000000    13000000000              0 1.28e11 1.5 e11 0      
3 Ham8Y         3520000000  8527443931.  55000000000   2.38e10   3.14e10 2.19e10     2050000000     3520000000    17500000000 5.5 e10 6.38e10 1.89e10
# … with 3 more variables: H2_Rep1 <dbl>, H2_Rep2 <dbl>, H2_Rep3 <dbl>
```

Comment: `NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `Condition_median`.`

Comment: @nik I couldn't reproduce that issue.  CAn you show your `packageVersion('tidyr')`

Comment: @packageVersion('tidyr')
[1] ‘1.2.0’

Comment: @nik I also have the same version.

Comment: @nik I used `1.0.8` for `dplyr` in case that is a difference

Comment: your code does not create any Condition_median column in the output .

Comment: @nik Here is what I get `> names(out2)
 [1] "Data"             "Condition_median" "Condition_SD"     "H1_median"        "H1_SD"            "H2_median"        "H2_SD"           
 [8] "Condition_Rep1"   "Condition_Rep2"   "Condition_Rep3"   "H1_Rep1"          "H1_Rep2"          "H1_Rep3"          "H2_Rep1"         
[15] "H2_Rep2"          "H2_Rep3"`

Comment: @> names(out2)
 [1] "Data"           "Condition_Rep1" "Condition_Rep2" "Condition_Rep3" "H1_Rep1"       
 [6] "H1_Rep2"        "H1_Rep3"        "H2_Rep1"        "H2_Rep2"        "H2_Rep3"

Comment: @nik I tried multiple times with your data and it is giving me the same output

Comment: @nik Can you change `mutate` to `dplyr::mutate` in case there is some masking?

Comment: @nik That is not a criteria.  I just wanted to know why it is not working for you when we have the same version.  Can you try on a fresh R session with only dplyr/tidyr loaded